# 'array index is greater than array upper bound for ...' error in OpenBUGS

Tags: arrays, indexing, winbugs

I'm having trouble running my OpenBUGS program. The model is syntactically correct but once the data is loaded, I can't compile because the error '**array index is greater than array upper bound for beta**' occurs. I have been checking everything but can't seem to find the mistake.

```
model
{

#priors

Sbeta ~ dunif(0,20);
variancebeta<-pow(Sbeta,2);
taubeta<-1/variancebeta;

Salpha ~ dunif(0,20);
variancealpha<-pow(Salpha,2);
taualpha<-1/variancealpha

lambda ~ dnorm(0,5)

gamma ~ dnorm(0,5)

t3Dref ~ dnorm(0,1)

zT ~ dnorm(10,3) 
a<-1/zT

zP ~ dunif(0,100)
c<-1/zP


#étude e

for(e in 1:Netude){

alpha[e] ~ dnorm(0,taualpha);

} #end etude e


#espèce i

for(i in 1:Nespece){

beta[i] ~ dnorm(0,taubeta);

} #end espece i


#courbe n

for(n in 1:Ncourbe){

logt3Dref[n]<-(log(t3Dref)+alpha[etude[n]]+beta[espece[n]]+(gamma*Matrice[n])+(lambda*Phase[n]))/log(10);
Mlogt3D[n]<-logt3Dref[n]+(Tref-Tempe[n])*a+(Pref-Press[n])*c;

variancet3D[n]<-pow(sigmat3D[n],2)
taut3D[n]<-1/variancet3D[n]

logt3D ~ dnorm(Mlogt3D[n],taut3D[n]);

} #end courbe n

}


#Data

list(Ncourbe=40, Nespece=2, Netude=3, espece=c(3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6), 
etude=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4), Matrice=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1), 
Phase=c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0), Press=c(500,500,500,500,500,500,300,300,300,300,270,270,600,600,600,600,600,600,270,270,270,270,270,270,400,400,400,400,400,400,600,600,600,600,600,600,600,600,600,600), 
Tempe=c(20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20), sigmat3D=c(19.246,22.12,63.38,61.24,90.74,148.125,2.495714286,20.95714286,17.2,15.74285714,25.24285714,10.41428571,31.66666667,33.53333333,35.11666667,66.6,38.5,50.6,57.88571429,57.75714286,57.22857143,57.18571429,58.17142857,56.51428571,22.32857143,16.08571429,75.64285714,18.6,45.28571429,9.944285714,128.26,75.84,92.44,128.88,127.64,126.68,123.6,110.04,97.58,157),
Tref=20, Pref=459)
```

Answer (score 1):

You've only defined priors for beta[1] and beta[2], since Nespece = 2, but your definition of logt3Dref[n] uses beta[espece[n]], where espece[n] takes values of 3 or 6.  So it doesn't know what beta[3] and beta[6] are.  In the error message, the "array index" of 3 or 6 is greater than the "array upper bound" of 2.

Comment: Thank you Chris for your answer and your help. I finally sorted out my problem yesterday with the help of my boss. But thank you for taking time to help.